# NTLM authentication with Java outside Domain

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ntlm

My question is simple, the answer might be complicated though.

Can NTLM authentication be done outside a network from a tomcat server using Java code to do the authentication? If so, what sort of certificate/trust exchange is required? What other requirements are there?  Would it depend on the setup of the server needing to be authenticated against?

I can't find this exact question anywhere and am hoping for some general info on this, not a specific implementation, although that would be cool to see.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of NTLM, but common approach is to use LDAP AD.

Spring security has a good support on LDAP authentication: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html

You need to be familiar with your organization's AD structure. Below is sample configuration from JIRA LDAP AD setting which roughly highlight configuration item required to setup LDAP authentication

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info, in my specific case, I can't use LDAP due to a security restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer to this is to use something like SAML or OAuth to authenticate outside the network/domain.  Working on implementing SAML.